# How to return table as array using Javascript in Test Cafe

Tags: javascript, arrays, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I am trying to validate the whole table elements and want to return the table as an array, and then want to access each element..pls help.

Comment: Any output code that needs to be parsed?

Comment: I am getting this as output, when I run my code - [object Array Iterator]

Comment: My async function look similar like this one

Comment: for (let i = 0; i <= elements.length - 2; i+=2) {
            const customerName  = elements[i+1].textContent;
            const saleAmount = elements[i].textContent;

            if (customerName && saleAmount)
                array.push(`Customer ${customerName}: ${saleAmount}`);
        }

        return array;
    });

Answer (score 3):

Please look at the following example which demonstrates how to use TestCafe to check a table state:

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

fixture `fixture`
    .page `https://jsfiddle.net/gv69jqrx/1/`;

test('Obtain array', async t => {
    await t
        .switchToIframe(Selector('#editor').find('[name="result"]'));

    const getCountries = ClientFunction(() => {
        const countries  = [];
        const columnKeys = ['country', 'capital', 'population', 'language'];
        const rows       = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

        for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            const cells   = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
            const country = {};

            if (!cells.length) continue;

            for (let j = 0; j < cells.length; j++)
                country[columnKeys[j]] = cells[j].textContent;

            countries.push(country);
        }

        return countries;
    });

    await t
        .expect(getCountries()).eql([
            { 
                country:    'USA',
                capital:    'Washington, D.C.',
                population: '309 million',
                language:   'English'
            },
            { 
                country:    'Sweden',
                capital:    'Stockholm',
                population: '9 million',
                language:   'Swedish'
            }
         ]);
});
```

If your scenario is different, describe it in greater detail. The test code and the test page example would be very helpful.

Comment: ok cool, thanks again...I did in very similar way and it worked.